# How to extract biggest Polygon from MultiPolygon in GeoPandas?

Tags: shapely, geopandas

Given a Shapely MultiPolygon, how can I extract the biggest Polygon?

For example, given a MultiPolygon as follows:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon

multipolygon = MultiPolygon([Polygon([(0,0), (1,0), (1,0.25), (1, 0.5), (1,0.75), (1,1), (0,1)]),
                             Polygon([(2,0), (1.2,0.25), (1.2,0.25), (1.2,0.75), (2,0.75)])])
```

[image]

How can I get just the largest part?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
max(multipolygon, key=lambda a: a.area)
```

The built-in max function used this way will return the item from the list where `lambda a: a.area` is maximized.

Comment: That's really elegant. Love these one-liners!

Answer (score 2):

I think I found an interim solution, if there is a better way please let me know!

```py
def get_biggest_part(multipolygon):

    # Get the area of all mutipolygon parts
    areas = [i.area for i in multipolygon]

    # Get the area of the largest part
    max_area = areas.index(max(areas))    

    # Return the index of the largest area
    return multipolygon[max_area]
```

Comment: Slightly quicker method proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193498/pythonic-way-to-find-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-a-list

Answer (score 1):

As of shapely 2.0.2 (and may be earlier versions), you need to append `.geoms`:

```py
max(multipolygon.geoms, key=lambda a: a.area)
```